# Scratch is not responding when I try to edit a file

Tags: code

When I try to open Scratch, a window appears and I need to use the `"force close"` option.
[image: Screenshot of force close]

How may I solve this problem?

I really like the Scratch UI, so I want to use this application.

When try to use `scratch-text-editor` from the terminal , I get this error.

[image: Scratch Terminal Errors]

Comment: Try running `scratch-text-editor` from the terminal and let us know what the output is.

Comment: update my question and picture of terminal output

Comment: Does scratch is opened or not?

Comment: it's not opened.
when try to open scratch , scratch is not responding window appear and need to force close .

Comment: Are you using a different theme other than elementary?

Comment: no am not , Just change icon only. Going back to elementary icon not solve my problem.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with terminal plugin. Try to disable this plugin (gsettings: org.pantheon.scratch.settings).

Comment: Scratch does not handle large files well.

Answer (score 3):

You can try clearing the currently opened files in Scratch since I had this problem because I opened a big file. To clear the currently opened files list run `gsettings set org.pantheon.scratch.settings opened-files []`

Comment: @coppettim Can you mark this the as answer?

Comment: Then we both get some reputation if you mark as answer (+2 for you and +10 for me)

Answer (score 2):

If I type `gsettings set org.pantheon.scratch.settings opened-files []` I get `The key "opened-files" doesn't exist"`(something like that. My System is in Spanish). I write what I did in case it helps someone else.

I installed dconf-editor via `sudo apt install dconf-editor`, then I opened it and followed the route `org » pantheon » scratch » settings` and there I emptied the `[]`. It's the same that the command does, but in a visual way.

Comment: using the dconf-editor solves the problem. Also emptied the opened-files-view1 and opened-files-view2.  Thanks.