# Scratch editor binary file load and session restoring problems

Tags: code

I'm on Freya. Scratch editor can't load (large?) binary files. It get stuck. Then if I force-close the app, when reopening it, it tries to restore the session and get stuck again. How can I 'recover' it ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try moving those binary files to some other directory or just changing their names. Then open up scratch and it wont try to open those files. After that you can just move back those files or change back their names.

You can find a nicer solution in the answer by [Suici Doga](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/3757/suici-doga) of [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3000/scratch-is-not-responding-when-i-try-to-edit-a-file?rq=1).

Comment: Would you please accept the answer if it solved your problem? Thanks.